# Can not run docker command directly after installation on windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

I installed docker on windows 10 with DockerToolbox (1.11.2) executable. However, I can't evaluate my environment using `docker-machine env default` directly.

Instead, only when I use this command

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe env default *
```

Can I evaluate the environment?
When I want to check help information, I also have to run

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help
```

In their official tutorial: [Install Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/), they mentioned that after installation, I could use `docker`,`docker-machine`,`docker-compose` directly.

In fact, I found this problem when I met this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: An error occurred trying
to connect: Post https://192.168.99.103:2376/v1.23/containers/create:
dial tcp 192.168.99.103:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond..
```

And I solved it by restart my machine, and evaluate it again with the full path of the executable.
Some thing interesting is that `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default` worked for me while `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` failed.

I can just add those executable to environment variable on Windows.
But I want to what's happaning to that installation which caused this problem.

Screenshot of my installation console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `docker-machine env` at all: you can simply ssh to your machine, and make your docker commands from there.

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

Second, try and use those commands from a regular CMD session (you don't need a bash).
As documented in [`docker-machine env`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/):

```
$ docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd dev
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\captain\.docker\machine\machines\dev
set DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=dev
# Run this command to configure your shell: copy and paste the above values into your command prompt
```

(Replace "`dev`" by the name of your machine, like "`default`" for instance)

Comment: This actually solved the problem, and I just figured out it's a safe reminder for windows user. If they didn't install docker properly, they might have to use `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe env default *` in order to execute the command

Comment: @LingboTang Note: there is no "installation" for docker-machine: just copy/curl/wget https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.7.0/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe anywhere you want, rename it `docker-machine.exe` and you are good to go.